# Java performance for loop

Tags: java, performance, loops, for-loop

I have algorithm with `for` loops, that looks like:

```
for(A : collection) {
  for (B : A.collection) {
     for (C : B.collection) {
        do something with C instance
     } 
  } 
}
```

What is the best way to optimize the performance of this nested for loops?

For example use `LinkedHashMap`?

Thank you.

Comment: Fastest collection is native array - if you can use array with for(;;) loop - it will be fastest.

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I'll gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that the program will spend most of its time in the `do something with C instance` part. In this case, optimizations will probably not be worthwhile.

Aside from that, iteration speed depends on the type of collection. Arrays and `ArrayList` are fastest. Iteration over `LinkedList` and most other containers are slower because element access requires additional indirections. The `Vector` is also slower because of synchronization overhead.

Optimization will be most effective for the inner loop because it will be executed more often than the outer ones.